# Return URL Occasionally Being Used on First iFrame Load - Even When Doc Is Not Signed

Tags: docusignapi

We are creating an envelope from a template and then requesting the URL to view the envelope in an iFrame.  However, we are infrequently encountering that the returnUrl is being loaded in the iFrame instead of the Docusign document.  We estimate this happens between 1 in 50 to 1 in 75 envelope instantiations.

It only happens on the first try of viewing a new envelope - subsequent URL requests load the document correctly.  We are using appdemo.docusign when we encounter this - we have not gotten to the point of trying it on production yet.

Is this a known bug?  I have verified that everything is working okay on our end - it just appears that Docusign is forwarding us to the returnUrl incorrectly.

Comment: What event code do you get on the returnUrl?  You should see a query parameter named "event" that will indicate why you've been sent there.

Comment: I will add some logging to determine this.  The returnUrl doesn't quite make sense for our application since we are using an iFrame, but we are making it work by using a static Github Page as our return URL.  https://top-agent.github.io/system-landing-pages/